# How to draw a graph of path between points in (x,y)-steps stepwise, rather than straight-line?

Tags: r, graph, ggplot2

Some weeks ago I started working with R and this is the first problem where I could not find an answer. Here is a simple example of the data I want do show in a path-graph:

```
library(ggplot2)

x = c(1, 3, 6, 8, 9, 4, 6, 8, 12)

y = c(3, 7, 12, 14, 18, 23, 24, 30, 34)

p = qplot(x, y) + geom_path()

print(p)
```

My problem is the diagonal connections between the lines. I want to connect them stepwise, thus first moving horizontal and then vertical (or vica versa). I found the geom_step , but I was not able to **draw a path** stepwise.

If anyone can help - this would be very fine!

Answer (score 2):

Use `geom_step`:

```
qplot(x, y) + geom_step()
```

**EDIT** after OP comment:

I don't think that there is a ggplot2 geom that do what you want, but here a manual solution where I insert points between each 2 existing points. The solution is not finished ( should take care of one or 2 particular cases) but it is a good start, and can easily generated to create your own gem.

```
dat <- data.frame(x=x,y=y)
rownames(dat) <- paste0(seq_len(nrow(dat)),'x')
res <- t(sapply(seq_len(nrow(dat)-1),function(x){
  row1 = dat[x,]
  row2 = dat[x+1,]

  if ( row1[1]>row2[1])
    c(x=min(row1[1],row2[1]),
      y = min(row1[2],row2[2]))
  else
    c(x=max(row1[1],row2[1]),
      y = min(row1[2],row2[2]))
}))
rownames(res) <- paste0(seq_len(nrow(res)),'y')

dat <- rbind.data.frame(dat,res)

dat <- dat[mixedorder(rownames(dat)),]
ggplot(dat) + geom_path(aes(x=x,y=y))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but the geom_step() does not produce the needed results. geom_step connects alls points in the graph from left to right (the same as geom_line). But I need a way to connect the points in the order that they are presented in the data set (like geom_path) - but this stepwise.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your suggestion. This helped to find the best solution for me. Here is my final solution for the problem:

> d.1 <- data.frame(x=x,y=y)
>
> rownames(d.1) <- paste0(seq_len(nrow(d.1)),'x')
>
> y.t <- y[-length(y)]
>
> x.t <- x[-1]
>
> d.2 <- data.frame(x=x.t,y=y.t)
>
> rownames(d.2) <- paste0(seq_len(nrow(d.2)),'y')
>
> d <- rbind.data.frame(d.1,d.2)
>
> d <- d[mixedorder(rownames(d)),]
>
> ggplot(d) + geom_path(aes(x=x,y=y))